# Google Maps Reviews: How do I get my site included?

Tags: google-maps, seo

I am NOT asking about getting a business added to Google Places. I'm asking about the 'user reviews' that show up on a Google Places listings. They seem to be pulled out from other review sites, like urbanspoon.com, etc.

Is this something that Google does by itself, or is there an API or mechanism to get your site included as a source of reviews?

In other words, can I get user reviews from my site something.com included in Google Places/Maps?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use microformats or as Google calls them, *rich snippets*. This blog post contains links to Google's information on the subject. http://blumenthals.com/blog/2010/09/22/google-announces-full-support-for-microformats-in-local/